# How do I download all submodules of a github project in cocoa?

Tags: git, cocoa, github, cocoapods

I am not an experienced user of git or github.

I am trying to use this module: https://github.com/blommegard/APNS-Pusher

I download it and issue the commands

```
pod install
```

and it shows

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing SBAPNSPusher (2.2.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `Test.xcworkspace`.
```

I think thats it. I try to run the project and I see this error:

```
#import <MGSFragaria/MGSFragaria.h> ... **MGSFragaria/MGSFragaria.h file not found**
```

I see that there is a folder named `Vendor/Fragaria` on the project and inside I see `Fragaria.xcodeproj` in red. I see that fragaria is another project of github but is a huge one. I am not shure how to integrate that on this project.

wasn't the command `pod install` supposed to install all dependencies? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/SBAPNSPusher/2.2.1/SBAPNSPusher.podspec.json#L13-L16) for this library doesn't instruct CocoaPods to do this. The `source` attribute needs to include `:submodules => true` for this ([documented here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source)).

You can update this by contacting the library owner.

Comment: so, unless the owner add this line, I am hopeless?

Comment: Well I assume this exclusion was intentional. But you should [open an issue](https://github.com/blommegard/APNS-Pusher/issues) on the GitHub repo to figure it out.

Comment: like I said, I barely know how to use github. Thanks anyway.